# Using switchMap operator twice in ngrx/effect dispatches multiple actions continuously

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I just started using **ngrx** and **ngrx/effects**.

In the following code using `switchMap` twice causes multiple `adminActions.GetAllStaffStart` , `adminActions.GetAllStaffSuccess({staff: data.results,cursors: data.cursors,totalCustomer: data.totalCustomer,});` and `adminActions.GetAllStaffFail({ errorMessage: message })` and  to be dispatched continuously

```
GetAllStaff = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(adminActions.GetAllStaffStart),
      switchMap(() => this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectAdmin)),
      switchMap((admin) => {
        return this.adminService
          .getAllStaff(
            admin.items_per_page,
            admin.cursors.after,
            admin.cursors.before
          )
          .pipe(
            map((data) => {
              return adminActions.GetAllStaffSuccess({
                staff: data.results,
                cursors: data.cursors,
                totalCustomer: data.totalCustomer,
              });
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
              let message;
              console.log(error);

              if (error.error && error.error.message) {
                message = error.error.message;
              } else {
                message = "Error fetching all staff";
              }
              return of(
                adminActions.GetAllStaffFail({ errorMessage: message })
              );
            })
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

This Works

```
GetAllStaff = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(adminActions.GetAllStaffStart),
      concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectAdmin)),
      switchMap(([action, admin]) => {
        return this.adminService
          .getAllStaff(
            admin.items_per_page,        
            admin.cursors.after,
            admin.cursors.before
          )
          .pipe(
            map((data) => {
              return adminActions.GetAllStaffSuccess({
                staff: data.results,
                cursors: data.cursors,
                totalCustomer: data.totalCustomer,
              });
            }),
            catchError((error) => {
              let message;
              console.log(error);

              if (error.error && error.error.message) {
                message = error.error.message;
              } else {
                message = "Error fetching all staff";
              }
              return of(
                adminActions.GetAllStaffFail({ errorMessage: message })
              );
            })
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

Using `concatLatestFrom` from `@ngrx/effects` works.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this might be happening because you are subscribing you the store selector

```
 switchMap(() => this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectAdmin)),
```

Which probably gets triggered causing logic in your effect to be executed

Comment: i thought it suppose to **subscribe** to the **store** when the `action` dispatched matches the action in the `ofType`